# Get ERC-20 token balance

Tags: code-golf, internet

[Ethereum](https://www.ethereum.org/) is a blockchain platform. It has its own native cryptocurrency, ether, but in this challenge, we'll be focusing on its ability to run smart contracts.

The [ERC-20 standard](https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/blob/master/EIPS/eip-20-token-standard.md) describes an implementation of fungible tokens within a smart contract. Some examples of this implementation are [EOS](https://etherscan.io/token/EOS), [OmiseGo](https://etherscan.io/token/OmiseGo), and the [Golem Network Token](https://etherscan.io/token/Golem). In this challenge, your job is to find the amount of tokens owned by a certain address using the fewest bytes possible.

The standard defines a `balanceOf(address)` contract method which is simple enough to use; however, it returns it in terms of a much smaller unit. To get the actual balance, you must divide the result by 10 to the power of whatever the `decimals()` method returns. For example, calling `balanceOf(0x4530d03744d7ef769025623d31966da1e8485eef)` returns `1.500000000000015e+21`, and dividing it by 10^`decimals()` (10^18) results in the true balance of `1500.000000000015`.

### Notes

- Assume that the computer that your program/function/etc. will be running on is running a fully-synced [Geth](https://github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum) node on the Ethereum mainnet with the [JSON-RPC](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/JSON-RPC) endpoint listening on the default port of `localhost:8545`.
- Your program should take two inputs: the token contract address (e.g. `0xea097a2b1db00627b2fa17460ad260c016016977`) and the wallet address (e.g. `0x4530d03744d7ef769025623d31966da1e8485eef`). Input can be taken in any reasonable format, such as a string, an integer, or an array of bytes (NB: Ethereum addresses are 20 bytes long).
- It should have one output: the token balance of the address in any reasonable format. Cases where the balance is zero must still be handled.
- Loss of *fine* floating-point precision in the *final* balance (e.g. the 17th or 18th decimal after dividing the balance by 10^`decimals()`) is okay.
- The ERC-20 standard technically says that the `decimals()` method might not be implemented; however, you may assume that it is.
- The use of libraries like [web3.js](https://github.com/ethereum/web3.js/) is permitted, but discouraged.
- [Standard loopholes](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1061/loopholes-that-are-forbidden-by-default) are obviously not allowed.

### Test Cases

```
token, wallet -> balance
0xea097a2b1db00627b2fa17460ad260c016016977, 0x4530d03744d7ef769025623d31966da1e8485eef -> 1500.000000000015
0xab95e915c123fded5bdfb6325e35ef5515f1ea69, 0x4530d03744d7ef769025623d31966da1e8485eef -> 317.18737335873794694
0x6810e776880c02933d47db1b9fc05908e5386b96, 0x3257bde8cf067ae6f1ddc0e4b140fe02e3c5e44f -> 8495410
0xb64ef51c888972c908cfacf59b47c1afbc0ab8ac, 0x0be3dead1ba261560362361838dd9671a34b63bb -> 314873.06011271
```

### Reference Implementation

A reference implementation written in [Crystal](https://crystal-lang.org/) can be found [here](https://gist.github.com/nickbclifford/56efe3ebee672db64471b987ab725747).

Comment: Sandbox link [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/14496/65298).